# Powerbuilder Date from dropdown and initialization

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a powerbuilder datawindow with a field that has a drop-down arrow that will show you a calendar to pick a date, when user select a date and tab to next field (the date field is validated for spaces and Isdate). but changes his mind and goes back and deletes the select date and tabs out....the application crashes showing a PB screen message. How can I initialized the field to be spaces without causing the application to crash, Since the date field is not a required field.... I am using Powerbuilder 12.5 classic.

Comment: Any messages along with the crash?  How is the field initialized when the window opens? (retrieved from the DB as a NULL)?

Answer (score 1):

You said "*(the date field is validated for spaces and Isdate)*" & "*Since the date field is not a required field....* " since the date field is not necessary then why are you doing validation. remove that validation code. If you want then while saving the record or whatever the operation you doing check the date field, if that field is empty then make it as Null. Do this validation on button click event or some other event. So your app wont return any error. In general to avoid app crash try to handle the system error event on the application object.

Regards

Raj